# SQL get names who didnt work on a project

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to retrieve the names of people who didn't work on a project in PostgreSQL.

I got a table named `employees` with their `names` and `ssn`.

My second table is called `works_on` and includes `ssn` and `project_number`

`ssn` here is a `foreign key` from `employees`

Now I tried the following:

```
SELECT fname,lname
FROM werknemer w
JOIN werkt_aan wa 
ON (wa.ssn = w.ssn)
WHERE wa.ssn <> w.ssn
```

But this returns nothing, but I need 1 name who is not working on a single project.
Can someone explain to me how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `SELECT fname,lname
FROM werknemer w
left outer JOIN werkt_aan wa 
ON (wa.ssn = w.ssn)
WHERE wa.ssn is null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually solved using a `NOT EXISTS` query:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where not exists (select *
                  from works_on wo
                  where wo.ssn = e.ssn)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easy with `NOT IN`:

```
select * from employees
where ssn not in (select ssn from works_on)
```

Alternative with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT fname,lname
FROM employee w
LEFT JOIN works_on wa 
ON (wa.ssn = w.ssn)
WHERE wa.ssn IS NULL
```

This alternative is useful as you sometimes have more complicated requirements that can't easily be expressed with `IN` or `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT fname,lname
FROM werknemer w
WHere w.snn not in (Select wa.ssn from werkt_aan wa)
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to use NOT IN and a subquery here